# c++ std::set insert causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, stl, set

All-

I can't quite figure out why this piece of code is resulting in a segmentation fault... Any help would be great.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    int _x;

    A(int x){
        _x = x;
    }
};

bool fncomp(A a1, A a2){
    return a1._x < a2._x;
}

int main(){
    bool(*fn_pt)(A,A) = fncomp;

    set<A, bool(*)(A,A)> testSet;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout << i << endl;
        A a(i);
        testSet.insert(a);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
0
1
Segmentation Fault
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, look at your code. You declared a function `fncomp`, but are you really using that function anywhere? You initialize `fn_pt` with it, but `fn_pt` is not used anywhere. Doesn't it seem strange to you? How do you expect your `testSet` object to know that you want it to use your `fncomp` as the comparator, if you never ask your set object to use that function?

You declared your set `testSet` with an ordinary function pointer type `bool(*)(A,A)` as a comparator type. That's the *type* of the comparator. Now, you have to pass the actual *value* of the comparator to your set object through the constructor parameter

```
set<A, bool(*)(A,A)> testSet(fn_pt);
```

or

```
set<A, bool(*)(A,A)> testSet(fncomp);
```

(You don't really need that intermediate pointer `fn_pt`).

You forgot to do that, and the set object used the default constructor argument value for the comparator, which in this case is a null pointer. So, every time your `testSet` object tries to compare two elements, it performs a function call through a null pointer. No wonder it crashes.

Comment: I just ran into this myself. It's such a dumb mistake. But I don't understand why a default constructor is allowed. I declare the set to take a function, and I don't construct it with one, and that's ok?

Comment: @philo: Well, most people use *functional objects* as comparators, i.e. classes with overloaded `operator ()`. In that case the class type is used as template argument, while the comparator object itself (the constructor argument) usually gets default-constructed. A default-constructed comparator object is exactly what one needs in most cases, so it works fine.

Comment: @philo: Now, using *raw function pointer type* as comparator type (and raw function pointer as constructor argument) does not happen very often. This is considered a fairly "exotic" form of comparator. So, the implementation is tailored towards functional objects, not raw function pointers. And it works fine with functional objects. But if you want/have to use raw function pointers, you can do it. Just remember that there are some potential pitfalls in this approach. Remember to supply the actual pointer as constructor argument, since otherwise it will be silently initialized to null.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you get a compiler warning about the unused variable `fn_pt`?

The variable `testSet` has an internal comparator of the specified type `bool(*)(A,A)`.  Since you didn't initialize it, it was default initialized as NULL.  So when `testSet` tried to insert `A(1)`, it tried to invoke a null function pointer to figure out which order is correct.

You probably meant:

```
set<A, bool(*)(A,A)> testSet(fn_pt);
```